# frame HTTP carregando HTTPS

Tags: http, iis, ssl, https

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Estão com uma situação onde o certificado SSL foi instalado no IIS, mas não valida HTTPS, pois o certificado está para dominio.com.br e não para o IP Público do server (IIS).

Usei então o código abaixo para carregar o conteúdo do IIS no domínio que eu comprei.

```
<frameset rows="0,*" border="0">
<frame name="header" scrolling="no" noresize target="main">
<frame name="main" src="https://IP_PUBLICO_IIS">
<noframes>
<body></body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
```

Quando eu digito https://meudominio.com.br ainda fica Não-Seguro, ao inspecionar o certificado, ele está correto o CN=meudominio.com.br

Não sei o que fazer.

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Comment: Acho que você deveria começar pelo ponto em que o `<frameset>` é obsoleto e não deveria ser mais utilizado.

Comment: Como devo proceder ? Pois tenho 1 domínio comprado e o conteúdo em um IP Publico.

Comment: Não entendi, o domínio não está apontando para o seu IP? como está o apontamento do certificado para o seu site no IIS?

Comment: No IIS o certificado instalado é para o dominio.com.br, mas onde comprei o domínio ele faz um redirecionamento para o IP publico, ai como o certificado só valida se a URL estiver como dominio.com.br, fica como não seguro.

Comment: E não ficará mesmo, justamente por estar fazendo um redirecionamento...